# Python Pillow library not saving files with same name in same location

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library, odoo, file-handling

> Below is the code I am using to convert a binary data into image and then saving it

```
img = base64.b64decode(rec.image3)
img_conv = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img))
img_format = img_conv.format
img_conv.save('{}/{}'.format(path, rec.image_name), format(img_format))
```

> There are 4 images with same code and I want to handle the scenario where if all the file names are same in the same location, it should force to save the 4 images even though it has duplicate name.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you want to keep each file under a different name: Append '_' to the original filename as long as a file with such a name exists in your directory.

```
from pathlib import Path

path_to_save = Path(path, rec.image_name)

while path_to_save.exists():
    path_to_save = Path(str(path_to_save) + '_')
    
img_conv.save(path_to_save, format(img_format))
```